# Entity Component System, How To Optimally Traverse A Vector of Components

Tags: c++, events, components, entity, virtual-functions

I am trying to build an optimized entity component system. I know that in order to do this I should try to avoid unnecessary (small) virtual functions where the vtable lookup will cause more overhead than the actual function itself. I also know that a popular strategy is to let the entities only have a pointer to their components and let a Managing system contain the actual components themselves to increase data locality.

Question 1:
What I would like to be able to do is to set up an event-listener system. So for general upkeep and operations on a large number of entities I will perform operations in the EntityManagers array of components. When events are to be handled they are passed down to the Entity who will then delegate it to its components. The components will then handle the events and possibly pass more back to the entity to handle them once again.

My first question is should I be doing this? Should I be passing the event "down" or should I just let the EntityManager parse through its entire array looking for the components related to the specific entity?

Question 2:
Should I be using this many virtual functions? Some of them seem quite redundant like my GetType() function which is one line of code returning a static value. I know the majority of the overhead of a function like that will come from the vtable lookup.

Question 3:
My idea for the component system has already gotten quite complicated. I would like to have a weapon component, there are 3 types of weapons, each with their own class so that they each will have their own fire method. If I am to loop through an array of all components is their a way I can handle this without virtual functions? Would I have to separate each weapon type into a different array in order to handle it properly? Would I have to do the same thing with Body and every other type of component? Would I have to traverse an every weapon type array in order to find a particular entities weapon even though they can only have one?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Entity.h

```
#include <string>
#include "Transform.h"
#include "../Components/Component.h"
#include <vector>

class EntityManager;
class Event;

class Entity {
friend class EntityManager;
public:
    Entity(size_t);
    ~Entity();

    Transform transform;

    void HandleEvent(Event *event);

    size_t GetId() const;
    std::string GetTag() const;
    bool HasTag(std::string _tag) const;
private:
    Entity(size_t _id);
    void AddComponent(Component component);
    void RemoveComponent(Component *component);
    void SetTag(std::string _tag);
    Component* GetComponent(ComponentType type);

    size_t id;
    std::string tag;
    std::vector<Component> components;   //Entities only have references to their components
    std::vector<Listener> listeners;
};
```

Component.h

```
class Event;
class Entity;

enum ComponentType {
    ComponentType_Mesh,
    ComponentType_Camera,
    ComponentType_PointLight,
    ComponentType_DirectionLight,
    ComponentType_SpotLight,
    ComponentType_Body,
    ComponentType_Input,
    ComponentType_Weapon
};

class Component {
public:
    Component();

    bool enabled;

    virtual ComponentType GetType() = 0;
    virtual void HandleEvent(Event *event) = 0;

    void Invoke(Event *event);

    virtual void SetEntity(Entity *_entity);
    Entity* GetEntity() const;
protected:
    Entity *entity;
};

class Weapon : Component {
public:
    ComponentType GetType() override { return ComponentType_Weapon; }
    virtual void Fire();
};

class MachineGun : Weapon {
public:
    void Fire() override;
};

class Railgun : Weapon {
public:
    void Fire() override;
};

class Launcher : Weapon {
public:
    void Fire() override;
};

class Body : Component {
    ComponentType GetType() override { return ComponentType_Body; }
    int health;
};
```

Event.h

```
enum EventType {
    EventType_Null = -1,
    EventType_PhysCol = 0,
    EventType_WheelRayCol = 1,
    EventType_Accelerate = 2,
    EventType_Turn = 3,
    EventType_Fire = 4,
    EventType_Damage = 5
};
struct Listener {
    Component* comp;
    EventType type;
};

class Event {
public:
    int affectedID;
    const static EventType type;
    //vector<int> entityIDs;

    Event(int);

    inline int GetAffectedID();
};

class InteractEvent : Event {
public:
    int sourceID;

    InteractEvent(int, int);

    inline int GetSourceID();
};

class AccelerateEvent : Event {
public:
    using Event::Event;
    const static EventType type;
};

class FireEvent : Event {
public:
    using Event::Event;
    const static EventType type;
};
```

Comment: If you make an entity component system that uses `virtual` functions or inheritance at all you are probably doing it wrong. They are avoidable overhead.

Comment: @nwp: Does an entity component system consider sharing properties, attributes or functionality with other entities?  Inheritance helps with these concepts.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No it doesn't. The whole point of an ECS is that the properties, attributes and functionality of one entity are independent of that of another. There *can* be entities that happen to have the same property, but you do not want to hardcode that into the type system.

Comment: @nwp I would like to avoid virtual functions but I can't see another way of traversing an entities Components and calling the right HandleEvent without it

Comment: You are not supposed to traverse an entity's components. You are supposed to have systems that iterate over known components and handle events on them.

Comment: @nwp that answers one of my questions, but how do you implement polymorphism then? I want each of my different component classes to handle an event differently, how can I traverse all of the components in the system and handle each class differently?

Comment: You use `template <class T> std::vector<T> components;`. Whenever a `Some_component_type the_component` is added you do `components<Some_component_type>.push_back(the_component);`. In your system you do `for (auto &component : components<Some_component_type>)` to iterate over all of them. This is the general idea at least. In a real implementation you wouldn't use `std::vector` and you probably need some way to get the entity from a given component and a component from an entity and so on.

Comment: @nwp that makes sense and certainly removes the need for polymorphism, but what about entities with only one or two components? Doesn't it seem a little extreme to go through every single component type vector just to grab the one thats theirs? Is this still the more effective solution? Otherwise how would you know what componentTypes the entity has and which vector to look through to avoid looking through them all

Comment: Again, generally you don't need to know what components a certain entity has. Except when the entity gets destructed, because then you probably want it to take all its components with it. My solution to that was to use a `template <class Component_type> void component_deleter(Entity_id id) { components<Component_type>.erase(id); }`. Note that while `component_deleter` is a template the type is always the same, so you just add a `std::vector<void(*)(Entity_id)>` as a component to `components` and in `~Entity()` you call all of the component deleters.

Comment: It is unfortunate to have 1 pointer overhead per component in an entity. Maybe you can find a better way.

Comment: @nwp okay, just to make sure I'm understanding even if we end up traversing all of the different components in the system its still more effective than using a pointer right? Also what if we had an entity type and a reference to what an entity like that contained, that way you would only have to traverse the necessary lists. On another note if I was to store each of the lists in an unorderer map with keys of the componentType's would that be considered a nice way to find the list I want?

Comment: What does "its" refer to in the first question? I don't understand what you want to do in the second question either. For the data structure you should look into [`plf::colony`](http://www.plflib.org/colony.htm), but it should be easy to modify later, so ideally you just benchmark realistic scenarios and pick whichever container runs the fastest.

Comment: @nwp moreover what about events? Events generally only affect one or two components so do we traverse the entire list of components for each new event to act on the one or two components that they effect? My understanding is obviously limited so I am genuinely asking if this is typically faster. (Question 1) it's was referring to the entity passing events down to it's own components (EntityManager->Entity->Component). (Question 2) I think was pretty much solved because I was wondering how to avoid stupid virtual functions but the separation of lists seems like it will handle that

Comment: I have not found a use for sending events between components or entities. For example when a collision happens you might think that could trigger a collision event which needs to be handled. Instead you have a physics system that goes through all the physics bodies and when it finds a collision it handles it right there, no event needed. If you mean some other type of event describe it more.

Comment: @nwp The reason why I was thinking an event handling system was because then the components could "interact" with each other more. For example: One entity collides with a bullet, physics body handles the collision, spawns the takes Damage Event. Both the rendering component and the body component are interested in this event. The rendering component would like to show where it was hit, and the body component will like to account for the damage taken. This way I can just set up listeners for events as opposed to hardcoding in what needs to account for each type of event

Comment: Well, you could let components add a callback to a  `std::vector<std::function<void(const Event &)>>`-component so the system can call all the event handlers whenever an event fires. You need to find a way to make components remove their callbacks before they are removed without the `component_deleter` getting in the way without re-implementing that in every component, but it can certainly be done.

Comment: @nwp this is very interesting. So to make sure I understand this, we would set up a vector containing pointers to specific component EventHandling functions. Usually events are made for specific entities though, how would we know the components function was for a specific entity. Sorry my knowledge of function call backs is also limited. When the function call back is used will it have access to it's components data like entityID? Or is there another way to ensure the event is for a specific entity? Also would it be more efficient to sort handlers into different vectors that they listen for?

Comment: You can pass the entity (which the system knows) to the event handler. That way the event handler has access to all components of the handled entity. If you want to give specific events to specific entities you can make a `std::map<Event, std::vector<std::pair<Entity, Callback>>>` or something to that effect. It's really very flexible. If you put the callbacks into different vectors is mostly decided by the type. Same type -> same vector, different type -> different vector.

Comment: @nwp in the case above would it be more efficient just to just let the entity have pointers to it's components and let the entity handle the events? Or would that be less efficient?

Comment: Once you have 20 rep you can participate in [gamedev](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) and [C++ Q&A](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers) chat. Other people might have different views and experience.

Comment: You can't let the entities have pointers to the components because the component types are not known. Also you force every entity to carry those pointers even if they don't care about events. Just store them as components and make sure accessing components is fast.